# FutureBuilder snapshot Data does not return anything , Why?

Tags: flutter, async-await, sharedpreferences

Trying to get stored data by SharedPreferences But does not work ..

my main.dart :

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<User>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: SaadConstants.setValueFromLocal('app_lang','ar'),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot){
          return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            home: Scaffold(
              body:Wrapper(),
            ),
          );
        }
      ),
    );
  }
```

my wrapper :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    if (user==null) {
      return FutureBuilder(
        future: SaadConstants.getValueFromLocal('app_lang'),
        builder: (BuildContext contect , AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot){
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text('has data');
          }
          else return Text('None'); 
        }
      );
    }
    else{
      return Text('connect');
    }
```

it returns this widget : Text('None') ..

my setValue Function :

```
  static Future<String> setValueFromLocal(String key, String value) async { // Async func to handle Futures easier; or use Future.then
    SharedPreferences perfs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    perfs.setString(key.toString(),value.toString());
  }
```

my getValue Function :

```
  static Future<String> getValueFromLocal(String key) async { // Async func to handle Futures easier; or use Future.then
    SharedPreferences perfs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return perfs.getString(key);
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
return FutureBuilder(
    future: SaadConstants.getValueFromLocal('app_lang'),
    builder: (BuildContext contect, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      else if (snapshot.hasData)
        return Text("DATA: ${snapshot.data}");
      else if (snapshot.hasError)
        return Text("ERROR: ${snapshot.error}");
      else
        return Text('None');
    }
);
```

Your main.dart should also implement these conditions.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamProvider<User>.value(
    value: AuthService().user,
    child: MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: FutureBuilder<String>(
          future: SaadConstants.setValueFromLocal('app_lang', 'ar'),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            else if (snapshot.hasError)
              return Text("ERROR: ${snapshot.error}");
            else
              return Scaffold(
                body: Wrapper(),
              );
          }
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: it returns Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation Found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)

Comment: Found on github : 
No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io __the above will occurs when you setup the plugin for the first time, so it has to be reinstalled ...

Do uninstall and reInstal your application....

shareeditflag

Comment: yep, try reinstalling your app . Its not a problem from from the `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: this time it returns  : return Text('None'); .. :\

Comment: Its probably because in your shared preference there is no value found for the given key.

Comment: Edit : i wrongly deleted return on my getValue Function :p

Now it Works perfectly !
Thnak you man , such a great guy .